# Converting ARM code from rvds to linux gcc source

Tags: arm, neon

I have the below instruction in ARM NEON code. Can you please tell me the equivalent in gcc?

```
label
    DCFS 1.5
    DCFS -1.4
```

I am not sure but i think the only way to do the above in gcc is using a table.

PLease let me know if there is an equivalent representation in gcc.

Comment: Are you looking for gas equivalent? ".float ?"

Comment: Yup that worked.. thank you Auselen!!

Comment: Just for my info i wanted to know.. DCFS does alignment of the code.. How about .float?

Answer (score 1):

https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Float.html#Float

> .float flonums
>
> This directive assembles zero or more flonums, separated by commas. It has the same effect as .single.

I couldn't find any reference about alignment guarantees but from experiment it looks like there is none.

```
$ cat f.s 
.data
.byte 0xaa
.float 3.14
.byte 0x55
.text
test:
    mov r0, r1
$ as f.s -o f.o
$ objdump -s -j .data f.o

f.o:     file format elf32-littlearm

Contents of section .data:
 0000 aac3f548 4055                        ...H@U
```